# Google Analytics Filters: Hide Multiple Subdomains

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics, filtering

So I have several views for the subdomains I want to track and the site as a whole. What I would really like is to create a view where it excludes all subdomains - the problem being I don't have a list of them (1000s) and new ones are being created all the time.

I have the universal analytics installation. Is this possible?

I found this online `.*\.subdomain\.domain\.com` and applied it - but doesn't seem to work, so I'm imagining I haven't interpreted it appropriately.

Comment: So I found another solution below ... but that won't work cause we generally don't use the "www." version of our website.     

1. Filter Name: www Domain Only  
2. Filter Type: Predefined  
• — include only –traffic to hostname — that contain  
3. Hostname: www.yourdomain.com

Answer (score 1):

Admin->views->filters->create new->exclude->hostname->filter pattern (*.|^)example.com -> filter out everything, what has something before point before domain name[image: Admin->views->filters->create new->exclude->hostname->filter pattern (*.|^)example.com -> filter out everything, what has something before point before domain name]

Comment: I'm just getting an error "Regular expression is invalid".

Comment: try ^\.example.com

Comment: Nopes - Nada. Says Filter would not change data.

Comment: The patterns are regular expressions.   So `.*\.example.com` would match all subdomains.   Just using a `*` is "globbing" and not supported by regular expressions.